# Images embedded in HTML text not loading on Dropbox

Tags: html, dropbox

I can't see the embedded images upon opening an HTML file from Dropbox, however when the folder was on the local system, the images did load properly.

Here's the HTML text that I wrote:

```
<img src="files/image1.png">
```

The HTML page shows the following sign in place of rendering the image:

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If `files` is in the root directory .. and you are trying to access it from outside root directory .. You need a fwd slash -- `<img src="/files/image1.png">`

Comment: This still doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround that worked for me was to sync the Dropbox folder locally. I could thus view the same HTML page in order (without making any changes).

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure files in the dropbox are public, not private. if it is public, then, go to the picture in the dropbox, and right-click it. click to "copy image address". and paste it to the .
hopefully, this will help

Comment: Do you mean that I should replace the ```img src=``` for the image with the public link of that image? That seems impractical since I have around 50 images in the HTML page.

Comment: yes, I meant exactly like that. I do not see other options for doing that. you should either download all images and use them in the local folder or above-mentioned way.